# Definition of the algebraic intersection number of oriented closed curves.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, surfaces, homology-cohomology

Can anyone point me to a reference (book/paper) where I can read up on the 
the *algebraic intersection number* of closed curves on an orientable surface? In [this paper by John Franks](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02100612) it is
used to prove Proposition 2.7. The only resource where I could find something is [Farb and Margalit: A primer on MCGs](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~bgabi/Farb%20Magalit%20January%202011%20version.pdf). It says there on page 28:

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two oriented, transverse, simple closed curves on an oriented surface $S$. The algebraic intersection number $\hat{i}(\alpha,\beta)$ is defined as the sum of the indeces of the intersection points of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where an index of an intersection point is $+1$ if the *orientation of the intersection agrees with the orientation of $S$* and $-1$ otherwise.

1. First of all, I can't really make sense of the notion of agreement of the orientation of an intersection with the orientation of the surface. What I could imagine is choosing one of the curves ($\alpha$) as a reference and counting an intersetion with $+1$ if the other curve ($\beta$) crosses $\alpha$ from left to right and with $-1$ if $\beta$ crosses $\alpha$ from right to left.
2. In Farb and Margalit's book it is mentioned that this intersection number is invariant for homologically equivalent loops. Does anyone know where I can find a proof?

Comment: Back in the day, the standard introductory reference for intersection theory was _Differential Topology_ by Guillemin and Pollack. Your surmise for "1." is essentially correct; you just need to fix orientations for each curve, as well as for the ambient surface (so that "left-to-right" makes sense). I don't recall whether G-P addresses "2."

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I will have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a clearer way of saying it is that if two oriented submanifolds $N_1, N_2$ intersect transversaly at a point $x$ of an oriented manifold $M$, then their intersection number is $+1$ if first a direct basis of $T_x N_1$, then a direct basis of $T_xN_2$ forms a direct basis of $T_xM$.

Comment: By **direct basis** you mean a reference with a given orientation? Is this the usual convention? Thanks.

Comment: What about general, not necessarily differentable manifolds (I am interested in surfaces)?