# simple closed curve is nullhomologous iff is separable

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

**A simple closed curve $\gamma$ in an orientable genus $g$ surface $M$ is nullhomologous if and only if $M \setminus \gamma$ consists of two connected components, one of which is a surface $N$ with $\partial N = \gamma$.**

Could anybody prove this or show a book where it's clearly explained?

Comment: Which direction of implication ("if" or "only if") is more unclear? If you understand one of them, then we can focus on the other. (If so, put that information in your question.)

Comment: unfortunately, i have no idea, so let's say "only if".

Comment: Probably an approach using Mayer Vietoris here will help. Consider a cylindrical wedge $C(\gamma)$ which is a small open neighbourhood around $\gamma$ which also deformation retracts onto $\gamma$ and let $U=C(\gamma)$ and $V=M\setminus\gamma$. Try computing homology using Mayer Vietoris in this case.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is a special case of "Poincare duality", see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859934/definition-of-the-algebraic-intersection-number-of-oriented-closed-curves?rq=1). Guillemin and Pollack is my favorite reference.

Suppose you have a nonseparating simple loop $a$ in $S$. Since $a$ is nonseparating, there exists a simple loop $b$ in $S$ which crosses $a$ transversally in exactly one point. Orienting these loops, we can assume that this intersection is positive. Oriented loops in $S$ define cycles and, hence, elements of $H_1(S;Z)$; since the oriented intersection number $I(a,b)$ is independent of the representative of the homology class, it follows that such $a$ is homologically nontrivial.

Conversely, suppose that $a$ separates. Then for every simple loop $b$ in $S$ transversal to $a$, the oriented intersection number $I(a,b)$ is zero (all intersection points come in pairs with opposite signs). Therefore, $a$ is null-homologous. You can also see this directly, without appealing to Poincare duality: Let $M\subset S$ be a subsurface with boundary bounded by $a$. Triangulate $M$ and orient 2-simplices consistently. The sum of these oriented simplices is a 2-chain whose boundary is $a$, regarded as a triangulated 1-cycle.

The same argument works in all dimensions, when you use closed (triangulated) hypersurfaces in a triangulated manifold. (This can be also done topologically or in the smooth category.)

Comment: Nice answer. I'm trying to verify that "$a$ nonseparating  $\Rightarrow  \ \exists b$ with $I(a,b)=(\pm)1$". If $a$ is nonseparating in $S$, $S\setminus U$ is path-connected, where $U$ is an open tubular neighborhood of $a$ in $S$. The boundary of $S \setminus U$ can be viewed as two disjoint copies of $a$, Path-connectedness implies that a point $x_0$ in one boundary component can be joined to the corresponding copy of $x_0$ in the other boundary component via a path (with no self-intersections). Isotopy ensures transversal intersection. (This then determines the desired loop in $S$ itself.)

Comment: @squirrel: Yes, what you wrote is correct. Same thing works for hypersurfaces in higher dimensions as well.